# How can I stop a buffer overrun in Windows Server 2019 after installing updates KB4551853 and KB4556441?

Tags: memory, windows-update, windows-server-2019

On 13th May 2020, our Windows server downloaded and began to install two updates: KB4551853 and KB4556441.  It restarted to finish the installation at 1:05am on Thursday morning.  However, when people arrived to work on Thursday morning (whether physically or virtually) the server was not working; it was unresponsive.

### Memory Leak

First of all I forced it to reboot by removing the power to it and then starting it again.  Once it started up again, however, it exhibited symptoms of having a memory leak.  It ran well for an hour or so, then became increasingly unresponsive, until it had to be restarted again.
I tried uninstalling the updates – which was possible for KB4551853.  However, this had no effect on the problem.
I looked in to going back to a restore point, but the “System Protection” tab is missing.  Perhaps we did not install the relevant “Rôle”.
Having noticed an error message about svchost.exe having a buffer overflow, I ran Windows’ memory test, but this saw no issues.  Neither did the BIOS RAM test.  Exact message:

> svchost.exe – System Error.
>   The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application.  This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of the application.

The Task Manager program indicates that the RAM becomes full (slowly), but that no process is taking up much RAM at all.  It has 16Gb of RAM, but the memory reports 99% full while the process taking up the most RAM is only using 17.1Mb!
Windows Start Menu and Settings seem the first things affected by the memory leak, the first programs that I would want to use that fail to work.

### Not the RAM

I did take the server apart and clean it and reseat the power connectors and RAM.  It made no difference.
Having researched saving the Active Directory settings, I converted the OS filesystem from FAT32 to NTFS using the Windows Server install disk, and then tried to do a “System state” backup.  However, the system became unresponsive before it completed.

### Attempted Reinstall

I tried to reinstall Windows Server 2019 over itself, while still keeping its settings.  However, the reinstall failed with error 0x800706BA – 0x20003, in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during INSTALL_UPDATES operation.  Suggested fixes included making sure the Windows update system is functional, so I ran the Windows Update Troubleshooter, and that found no errors.  They also include uninstalling non-Microsoft antivirus software, so I uninstalled our copy of ESET from the server.

### Other Attempted Fixes

I have also run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` followed by `sfc /scannow`, and `chkdsk c:`, but they have all found no errors and made no difference.

### Possible actions going forward

- Try disabling all the Startup programs to see if we can isolate what is causing the problem.
- I think Dell Support Assist recently updated; perhaps try uninstalling this software.
- Try to reinstall Windows Server again, having uninstalled ESET it might work.

Comment: How do you know it isn't the RAM? Have you done any memtest scans on it? You may need to use memtest to stress the memory to cause it to fail. Have you tried new sticks of memory?

Comment: Well, I admit no test is 100% efficient, but the most significant RAM test I have done so far is Windows' own memory test.  I can't remember what it is called, but it reboots the machine, tests the RAM, then boots up again.  Seemed pretty thorough.  Sorry, I suppose my headings aren't in the best places!

Comment: I have seen Windows memory tests come back clean, only for memtest to show failures. If you are getting blue screens like this, my first port of call would be to do a thorough memory test on it (if you aren't able to switch out the memory to test it that way)

Comment: A quick look on Google suggested that you run a virus scan in safe mode to check for malware. It could be a malicious program is causing the issues

Comment: Why exactly do you have Dell software installed on a Windows Server installation?  There are unconfirmed issues with both of those patches.  Users have reported issues that are solved by uninstalling those updates, but at this time, Microsoft has confirmed there actually is a problem or not.  **I suspect the memory leaks are from a device driver that might have also been updated the same day, and the problems described, simply exist due to the reboot by the installation of those patches.**  However, since disk based operations have failed, disk problems cannot be ruled out.

Comment: @Ramhound could you suggest how I might track down which drivers were recently updated?  Thanks

Comment: Windows Update History

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank everyone who posted because all your posts were helpful.
Second, the method I used to solve the problem is one suggested to me by Andrew Mills of datamills. It was to use the Windows diagnostic startup feature of Windows Server. You can access it through Control Panel > Administrative Tools > System Configuration > General tab. It allows you to load only basic devices and services during the boot, then you can enable other services one by one to see which one causes the problem. This is how I implemented the action listed at the bottom of my original question.
Using this method, I discovered to my surprise that the culprit was not Dell’s Support Assist, or anything to do with ESET, or the Windows Updates, but instead the install of Tenable Nessus Essentials. I had installed this for our upcoming Cyber Essentials Plus audit, and, being careful about such things, when I noticed that it came bundled with the unsupported Winpcap library, I updated it to the supported Npcap library, in compatibility mode. However, I suspect that Nessus doesn’t play nice with this library, and that that was what caused the Nessus service to consume all the RAM. Whether I’m right or wrong about that, having removed Nessus the server now functions properly. I installed Nessus for the audit on a different computer, and left it with the unsupported Winpcap library, and it didn’t crash that computer.